# Store the previous filtered data UIGIRD

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid, ui-grid

is there a way to keep the previous filtered data stored in a variable , i filter the data like below :

```
$scope.filteredRows =  $scope.gridApi.core.getVisibleRows($scope.gridApi.grid);
```

and wherever i create a value and do  a set like this :

```
$scope.newVar = $scope.filteredRows;
```

I'm always getting the current filter event that `$scope.filteredRows`  is filterd just the first time

Comment: try `$scope.newVar = angular.copy($scope.filteredRows);`.  You want a deep copy of the object, not a reference to it.

Comment: thanks, it gives me this error https://docs.angularjs.org/error/ng/cpws

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't use save the filter in the scope. Use a isolated scope or a normal variable. Then you can use the angular.copy method Claies mentioned above